# Binning continuous data to stack histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, data-visualization

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
USER.ID avgfrequency    orders  group
1   3   3.7821782   101 3
2   7   14.7500000  8   3
3   9   13.4761905  21  3
4   13  5.1967213   61  3
5   16  6.7812500   64  3
6   26  41.7500000  4   2
7   49  13.6666667  3   2
8   50  7.0000000   1   1
9   51  1.0000000   1   1
10  52  17.7500000  4   2
11  69  4.5000000   2   1
12  75  9.9500000   20  3
13  91  84.2000000  5   2
14  98  8.0185185   54  3
15  138 14.2000000  5   2
16  139 34.7500000  4   2
17  149 7.6666667   21  3
18  155 35.3333333  9   3
19  167 24.0000000  1   1
20  170 7.3529412   34  3
21  171 4.4210526   76  3
22  174 4.5000000   2   1
23  175 6.5781250   64  3
24  176 19.2857143  21  3
25  177 10.4864865  37  3
26  178 28.0000000  15  3
27  180 4.8461538   39  3
28  183 25.5000000  2   1
29  184 13.0000000  1   1
30  210 32.0000000  1   1
31  215 13.4615385  13  3
32  220 11.3611111  36  3
33  223 26.2500000  8   3
34  224 40.5000000  8   3
35  230 15.4000000  10  3
36  232 14.6666667  3   2
37  234 34.5833333  12  3
38  238 138.5000000 2   1
39  240 7.0000000   3   2
40  243 35.0000000  3   2
41  246 6.7500000   4   2
42  247 8.5000000   50  3
43  258 17.6666667  3   2
44  283 23.5000000  2   1
45  295 19.5625000  16  3
46  300 81.6666667  3   2
47  311 34.4166667  12  3
48  338 64.0000000  1   1
49  342 113.3333333 3   2
50  343 197.0000000 1   1
51  347 3.6923077   13  3
52  350 4.6666667   3   2
53  360 177.5000000 2   1
54  361 39.0000000  10  3
55  362 1.4000000   5   2
56  365 15.0000000  24  3
57  366 59.2000000  5   2
58  367 5.0000000   4   2
59  369 27.9285714  14  3
60  372 63.6666667  3   2
61  375 9.3750000   8   3
62  377 13.3225806  31  3
63  380 169.5000000 2   1
64  383 23.2352941  17  3
65  391 0.0000000   1   1
```

I want to split `avgfrequency` into different bins of width 10 and plot it as x-axis and on y-axis I want to show the count of USER.ID as histograms and in each bar I want to show count of USER.ID of different group with different color. So, each histogram would have three different colors for each bin.

Is it possible to do it in R ?

Comment: try `library(dplyr);library(ggplot2);df1 %>% mutate(bin= cut(avgfrequency, breaks=c(-Inf,seq(min(avgfrequency), max(avgfrequency), by=10), Inf))) %>%  group_by(group, bin) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% ggplot(., aes(x=bin, y=n, fill=factor(group)))+ geom_bar(stat='identity')`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. See below:

```
library(ggplot2) #load the ggplot2 graph package
data = data.frame(data) #make the dataset a R dataframe object
head(data,2) #just showing part of the data here.

 USER.ID avgfrequency orders group
       3     3.782178    101     3
       7    14.750000      8     3

#build graph
ggplot(data, aes(x=avgfrequency,fill=factor(group))) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,200,by=10),colour='black') + 
  xlab("Average Frequency") + ylab("Count of USER.ID") +
  scale_fill_manual("Group", breaks = c("1","2","3"), values = c("grey30","grey50", "grey70")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]